# WSL windows laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I recently started a laravel(8) project on my windows machine using WSL (Ubuntu 20.4) and docker. When reading data from the database I get the error 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]No such file or directory' for `DB_HOST=localhost` or 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' for `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`. However, this problem appears only when I start the whole project using `./vendor/bin/sail up`, when I boot the same project using `php artisan serve` the error does not appear for either `DB_HOST` configuration.

index function to show what is in DB

```php
public function index()
{
        dd(Customer::all());
}
```

Customer object

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'customers';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:WtHehq3ZteXPe6xEIij2TBblW7Qo3VUd5obTao3Kg4U=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://thc.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```

I already tried the solution with setting `unix_socket` to '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' and also to the result of `show variables like '%sock%';` of the 'socket' entry. I tried setting this value in both the '.env' file and in 'database.php'.

commands

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

also failed me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `docker`, you don't have to use any host as `localhost`, but rather use the service name as the host, for example, if you `docker-compose.yaml` is like this:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  superNiceDb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laravel'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT:-3306}:3306
```

You have to use `DB_HOST=superNiceDb` in your `.env` or wherever you are reading that value from.

This applies to any system, if you are using docker, this is the only way of referring to services, never use `localhost`.

Comment: For anything other than 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', even the `php artisan migrate` command doesn't work for me. I am attaching the contents of the `docker-compose.yml` file at the url https://pastebin.com/URUAGr2g.

Comment: Still, you have to use `DB_HOST=mysql`. It will work with `localhost` if you do `php artisan server` because you are not inside the docker container... when you run `phpunit`, you must be inside the container: `docker-compose exec laravel.test bash` and then do `./vendor/bin/phpunit`.